# Adding multiple radio buttons using a loop?

Tags: java

Say we have something like this...

```
JRadioButton jb1 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb2 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb3 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb4 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb5 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb6 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb7 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb8 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb9 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb10 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb11 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb12 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb13 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb14 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb15 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb16 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb17 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb18 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb19 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton jb20 = new JRadioButton();
```

Is there a way to add all of these radiobuttons using a loop instead of doing it one line at a time, or another cleaner way this just loops sloppy.

Should have cleared up a little bit what i meant is, is there a way to write a loop that will add all these buttons to a panel?

Comment: What stops you from trying?

Comment: Would an array of `JRadioButton` make your job easier?

Comment: this question doesn't show any effort. It's a simple `for`, these are the basics of java!

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy:

```
JRadioButton[] buttons = new JRadioButton[20];
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    buttons[i] = new JRadioButton();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using List and do something like:

```
List<JRadioButton> radioButtons = ..
for (int i =0; i<....;i++) {
    radioButtons.add(new JRadioButton());
}
```

You can then do something like:

```
JRadioButton buttonAtSomeLocation = radioButtons.get(0);// by index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use(*FOR EXAMPLE*)

```
ArrayList<JRadioButton> myList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
     myList.add(new JRadioButton());
}
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
     myList.get(i).doSomethingInJRadioButtonMetohd..... 
}
```